# ArcMap error drawing postgis layer - The number of points is less than required for feature

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, arcmap, postgresql

I have one big polygon called huc and a multilinestring called streams, I am running an intersection on between the two layers to clip the streams to the huc.

here is what I have so far

```
drop table if exists base_layers.streams_huc_clip;
create table base_layers.streams_huc_clip as
select s.*,case
    when st_within(s.shape,huc.shape) then s.shape
    when st_intersects(s.shape,huc.shape) then st_intersection(s.shape,huc.shape)
    end as geom2
        from postgres.streams s join base_layers.huc_hl_dissolve huc on st_intersects(s.shape,huc.shape);
```

--pretty straightforward query in postgis, this query returns with no errors and correctly gets displayed in QGIS.

However when I try and bring it into ArcGIS I get this error and it does not draw

```
One or more layers failed to draw:

lucz_2017.base_layers.streams_huc_clip:  The number of points is less than required for feature
```

so here are the following steps I tried after to do after it would not show up in ArcGIS to no avail.

dropped the original geometry so I just had one geometry column, renamed the new geom to shape

```
alter table base_layers.streams_huc_clip drop column shape;
alter table base_layers.streams_huc_clip rename geom2 to shape;
```

dropped the objectid and added new primary key, changed owners,

```
alter table base_layers.streams_huc_clip drop column objectid;
ALTER TABLE base_layers.streams_huc_clip ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
alter table base_layers.streams_huc_clip owner to base_layers;
```

created an index and tried updating the srid. none of this worked!

```
ALTER TABLE base_layers.streams_huc_clip ALTER COLUMN shape type geometry(multilinestring, 3424) using st_multi(shape);
CREATE INDEX streams ON  base_layers.streams_huc_clip USING GIST (shape);
```

also ran this query

```
SELECT * FROM public.geometry_columns ORDER BY type
```

which returned

[image]

I am thinking about running an st_dump on the geometry to turn it into a linestring, I will take any suggestions on why this layer is not displaying and what I can do to make it work

I ran an st_dump and turned the geometry into a linestring but I still got the same arcmap error

```
drop table if exists base_layers.streams_huc_clip;
create table base_layers.streams_huc_clip as
select (st_dump(geom)).geom as geom2,t.* from(
select s.*,case
    when st_within(s.shape,huc.shape) then s.shape
    when st_intersects(s.shape,huc.shape) then st_intersection(s.shape,huc.shape)
    end as geom
        from postgres.streams s join base_layers.huc_hl_dissolve huc on st_intersects(s.shape,huc.shape))t;
```

ST_MakeValid() did not help either

I make edits to these tables outside the ESRI stack.

Comment: So, I know that ArcMap has some quirks when connecting to PostGIS tables. Unless it's a requirement that you connect directly to the table, you might try exporting your table as a shapefile and opening that in ArcMap.

Comment: @notkilroy I've done this and it works but its a manual workaround I want to avoid. This database is going to have multiple users who also create postgis tables and I have run into this problem with a few other layers. So ideally a PostGIS/SQL method is preferred (if one exists)

Comment: This may be worth looking at even though it is for SQL Server: http://www.timmons.com/news/blog/identify-shapes-which-are-considered-valid-by-sql-server-but-invalid-by-arc

Comment: @PolyGeo cool I think that is my problem. is that c#? I only know python and SQL.. wonder if there is a way to reduce the coordinate precision with straight SQL or python

Comment: It looks like ArcObjects to me and that is not something that I code in.

Comment: same that is not in my skillset

Comment: If the issue is the difference in what levels of precision PostGIS and ArcMap can handle then you should be able to use [`ST_Snap_To_Grid`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SnapToGrid.html) to reduce the precision - getting the threshold right will take some trial an error, but shouldn't take too long. Based on @PolyGeo's link start with 0.0001.

Comment: Yes, try st_snap_to_grid and st_removerepeatedpoints to get rid of the points that gets identical. Use ST_Isvalid in the result to find what can be rendered.

Comment: got it to work! `UPDATE base_layers.streams_huc_clip
   SET shape = st_removerepeatedpoints(ST_SnapToGrid(shape, 0.001));` one of you post an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is caused by the tolerance ArcMap has for determining whether two vertices are identical vs the precision of the coordinates passed to it. The general concepts are well explained in great detail [here](http://downloads.esri.com/support/whitepapers/ao_/J9655_Understanding_Coordinate_Management_Esri_Whitepaper.pdf), and a more bite size form [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/the-properties-of-a-spatial-reference.htm), which also states Arc's defaults as:

- **0.0001** map units for **Resolution** (this is the cell size of the grid on which vertices are stored) - it determines the precision (no. of decimal places) at which coordinatess are stored.
- **0.001** map units for **Tolerance** which is the threshold below which two points are considered to be the same..

When ArcMap tries to read the geometry it maps vertices to the underlying grid, and removes repeated points, and so geometries can become invalid causing the error:

`The number of points is less than required for feature`

This can be solved by using PostGIS to snap vertices to an equivalent grid, and remove duplicated points before passing it to ArcMap. One way to do this is to use [`ST_Snap_To_Grid`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SnapToGrid.html) which snaps all vertices to an imaginary grid at a given tolerance.

This can be applied only to the table you wish to bring into ArcMap (preserving the precision of the original data from which the clip was derived) with:

```
UPDATE base_layers.streams_huc_clip SET shape = ST_RemoveRepeatedPoints(ST_SnapToGrid(shape, 0.001));
```