# Layers from a PostgreSQL/ArcSDE database connection are not showing in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase

We have a PostgreSQL/PostGIS SDE enabled database, but lately there is a strange issue when adding layers from this database to ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro. We can connect to the database without any issues and see all layers present in it. We can drag any layer in ArcGIS, but the layer is not visible in the data/layout view. It is however visible in the Table of Contents without an exclamation mark. We can even look in the attribute table, no problems there. If I select rows, the contours of the selection are visible, but not the polygon itself. Non registered SDE tables from the same database do work, so I have a feeling there is something wrong with ArcSDE. All tables also work in QGIS.

Is there anything I can do? I could not find similar issues online. Maybe there is something corrupt in the SDE registration?

[image: only the selection contour is visible, not the polygon itself][image]

On the pictures above: left how it is now, right picture is how it should be.

EDIT: I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5 and ArcGIS Pro 2.1. Postgres is on version 9.4. It was working just fine before, but suddenly it has this strange bug.

Comment: have you tried using a query layer?

Comment: This is probably a question for Esri Tech Support, since that's not the experience most have with PostgreSQL tables. You might try dropping and rebuilding the spatial index. Please  [Edit] the question to specify the exact versions of software in use.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Can I rebuild the spatial index in Postgres without messing up the SDE tables more?

Comment: Certainly. You can also use ArcGIS tools to drop and rebiuld indexes.

Comment: If I make a query layer from the same table, the layer is showing properly in ArcGIS. Does this point in some direction of what causes the error?

Comment: In addition: creating a new spatial index was not the solution, unfortunatly

Comment: and you get no error at all when you bring it in through the database connection?? I have had this happen b4 to me where the database connection does not work (but I was getting a drawing error) but the make query layer did work. it ended up being a discrepancy between the postgis and arcgis coordinate precision

Comment: check this answer out: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250165/arcmap-error-drawing-postgis-layer-the-number-of-points-is-less-than-required